# Proper way to dispose ashes of yagna

Tags: yajna, satyanarayana

What is the proper way to dispose the remaining ashes and sand of yagna( called hom in Bengali) of SatyaNarayan puja?

Note: Our family priest told to buried that at the Ishan direction of our land.

Comment: Do you think we know better than ur family priest?

Comment: I asked the question to know the scriptural basis of his answer (with due respect). That's why I added the note. And definitely some guy(hopefully you) answer with scriptural evidence as this is the best site on Hinduism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as the sand is concerned, it can be disposed anywhere. Because it is not NirmAlya. Burying it in soil is a good idea.

But as far as the ash is concerned, it's NirmAlya of the Homa. So, it should be disposed only as prescribed. I have seen people wearing some part of it as Tilaka and also keep some part of it in their Puja rooms.

As regards the direction IshAna Kona (North-East), the NirmAlyavAsni Devi (the Goddess who presides over NirmAlya) is to be worshiped in that direction only as said by Lord Shiva in the following verse:

> NirmAlyena yajed devim**ishe nirmAlyavasinim** |
>  NirmAlyam shirasA
>   dhAryam sarvAnge chAnulepanam ||
>
> .....
>
> Worship the Goddess NirmAlyavAsini **in the north-east corner**. Hold it
>   over the head and rub it as paste all over the body.
>
> **Bhairavi Tantram**

So, burying the ashes in the north-east corner seems to be the correct idea.

Now, as regards disposing NirmAlya, Lord Shiva says:

> Udake taru mule vA nirmAlyam tasya samtyajet ||
>
> .....
>
> The NirmAlya should be disposed in water or at the roots of trees.

(Note that Udaka means water. And Taru=Tree, Mula=Root.)

So, ashes can be immersed in water bodies and can also be poured in roots of trees.

Answer (score 2):

there are 2 ways to dispose ash .

1. Dispose it in river .
2. Buried in the land .

In second option you can bury ashes anywhere but mostly it is buried between Gate and entrance door of house.
My suggestion is collect the ashes in red cloth with one lemon bury it in front of your gate so that it helps to stop negative vibes to enter into home.

Comment: You should cite some sources.